# Neo4J - find nodes where the nodes related are a subset

Tags: neo4j

I'm very new to Neo4J and graph databases.

If I have a very simple graph where node A requires 1 to many node Bs.

Is there an efficient way to find those node As where the Bs they are related to is a subset of a give list.

eg given dataset:

```
typeA,rel,typeB

A1,REQUIRES,B1
A1,REQUIRES,B2
A1,REQUIRES,B3

A2,REQUIRES,B1
A2,REQUIRES,B4

A3,REQUIRES,B4

A4,REQUIRES,B5
```

I want to ask which of the As are fully covered by the given list of Bs

Examples:

```
 given B1,B2,B3 -> A1
 given B1,B3,B4 -> A2, A3
 given B1,B3,B4,B5 -> A2, A3, A4
```

If the given list of Bs doesn't have all of the Bs that A is related to then it should be excluded.

If there is an answer, would it scale to large numbers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I assume that:

- The nodes are labelled `:A` and `:B`, and have the `id` property.

  - For example, "A1" would be `(:A {id: 1})`.
- You pass a collection of the `:B` IDs of interest in the `{ids}` parameter.

The following query should do what you want.

```
MATCH (a:A)-[:REQUIRES]->(b:B)
WHERE b.id IN {ids}
WITH DISTINCT a
MATCH (a)-[:REQUIRES]->(bb:B)
WITH a, COLLECT(bb) AS bbs
WHERE ALL(x IN bbs WHERE x.id IN {ids})
RETURN a.id
```

[Here is a console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=9odjdf) that shows the results if the collection of `:B` IDs of interest is `[1, 3, 4, 5]`, which matches your last example. (Since the console does not support passing a parameter, I hardcoded the ID collection in the query.)

Description of the query, in order:

1. (First 2 lines) Find all the `:A` nodes that require a `:B` node having an ID the `{ids}` collection.
2. Remove duplicate `:A` nodes, so that we end up with distinct `:A` nodes (that require one or more `:B` nodes of interest).
3. Find all the `:B` nodes required by each of those `:A` nodes. (Some of these `:B` nodes may not be of interest.)
4. Associate with each of those `:A` nodes a collection of all its required `:B` nodes.
5. Filter out all `:A` nodes that require any `:B` nodes that are not of interest.
6. Return the IDs of the `:A` nodes that only require `:B` nodes that are of interest.

Assuming that you create an index for `:B(id)`, this query should be scalable.