# Find smallest subset of nodes that fully describes selection and not more

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create a query that gives me the smallest set of article numbers that fully describes the configuration of an order and not more than that.

In my graph I have two types of nodes: FeatureValues and Articles. One article can provide one or more FeatureValues. My input is a set of FeatureValues and I need to know which is the smallest set of article numbers that completely describes all my input values and doesn't add any additional FeatureValues. Best case scenario is that the requested configuration can be covered with one article number, but it's also possible that more than one article number is required:

Example dataset:

```
FV1:FeatureValue
FV2:FeatureValue
FV3:FeatureValue
FV4:FeatureValue

A1:Article-[:PROVIDES]->FV1
A2:Article-[:PROVIDES]->FV2
A3:Article-[:PROVIDES]->FV3
A4:Article-[:PROVIDES]->FV4

A5:Article-[:PROVIDES]->FV1 and FV2
A6:Article-[:PROVIDES]->FV1 and FV2 and FV3
```

Possible cases:

```
input = FV1, FV2
output: A5

input = FV1, FV2, FV3
output: A6

input = FV1, FV2, FV4
output: A4, A5
```

I found a somewhat related issue here: [Neo4J - find nodes where the nodes related are a subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376831/neo4j-find-nodes-where-the-nodes-related-are-a-subset). The result of that query is a list of all item numbers that provide the requested FeatureValues and don't add anything else, but it's not the smallest subset as some FeatureValues will be described by more than one article number.

Thanks!

Comment: in your possible cases the last one has `input: FV1, FV2, FV4` as input and `output: A4, A5`. But in your sample data `FV4` is only related to `A4`. I don't see how any output could be returned by that match. In the data it looks like `A4-[:PROVIDES]->FV4` is an island away from the other nodes. Are there a few relationships missing in the sample data?

Comment: Sorry for the last question, I think i understand now A4 and A5 is the smallest set of articles required to match all of the feature values in the input collection FV1, FV2, FV4.